# Generated dynamically a jsf form issue

Tags: java, jsf, data-binding, primefaces, richfaces

i am trying to render dymanically a form using jsf and a back bean which generates the form elements.

This is the code of the back bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "reviewReportBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ReviewReportBean implements Serializable {
... ... ...
private HtmlPanelGrid dynamicPanelGrid;
... ... ...
public HtmlPanelGrid dynamicPanelGrid() {
Application application = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
List childrenList = dynamicPanelGrid.getChildren();
childrenList.clear();
... ... ...
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try 
    {
    ... ... ...     
    HtmlOutputLabel label = (HtmlOutputLabel)application.createComponent(HtmlOutputLabel.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    label.setValue("Mpla Mpla Mpla");
    ... ... ...         
    childrenList.add(label);
    ... ... ...     
    String hq9 = "select ... WHERE it (:itid)";
    SQLQuery query9 = session.createSQLQuery(hq9);
    query9.setParameter("itid",imageTypeId);
    query9.addEntity(ReportFormFields.class);
    reportFormFields = query9.list();
    for(int i=0; i<reportFormFields.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.println(">> Field Id: " + reportFormFields.get(i).getRffFieldId());
        System.out.println(">> Field Name: " + reportFormFields.get(i).getRffFieldName());
        ... ... ...

        HtmlOutputLabel output = (HtmlOutputLabel)application.createComponent(HtmlOutputLabel.COMPONENT_TYPE);
        output.setValue(reportFormFields.get(i).getRffFieldLabel());
        childrenList.add(output);
        if(reportFormFields.get(i).getRffFieldType().equals("Option List")){
            HtmlSelectOneMenu combomenu = (HtmlSelectOneMenu)application.createComponent(HtmlSelectOneMenu.COMPONENT_TYPE);
            UISelectItems comboItems = new UISelectItems();
            String listOptions =reportFormFields.get(i).getRffFieldOptions();
            String array[] = listOptions.split("(?<!\\\\),");

            for(int j = 0;j<array.length;j++){
                System.out.println(">>> list option " + j + " is " + array[j]);
            }
            comboItems.setValue(array);
            combomenu.getChildren().add(comboItems);
            childrenList.add(combomenu);

            }else{
                HtmlInputText input = (HtmlInputText)application.createComponent(HtmlInputText.COMPONENT_TYPE);
                childrenList.add(input);
            }
            ... ... ...
        }
        ... ... ...
    }
    ... ... ...
    return dynamicPanelGrid;
    }
}
```

and this is how i try to generate dynamically the form in my view (xhtml) using the back bean code:

```
<h:panelGrid id="dynaPanelGrid7" 
binding="#{reviewReportBean.dynamicPanelGrid}" >
</h:panelGrid>
```

but the form is not generated at all. However if i call it like (direct call the method in order to generate the form):

```
<h:panelGrid id="dynaPanelGrid7" 
binding="#{reviewReportBean.dynamicPanelGrid()}" >
</h:panelGrid>
```

i get the following error:

```
can't parse argument number reviewReportBean.dynamicPanelGrid(): /views/view.xhtml @199,63 binding="#{reviewReportBean.dynamicPanelGrid()}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
```

but if subsequently i try to call it like:

```
<h:panelGrid id="dynaPanelGrid7" 
binding="#{reviewReportBean.dynamicPanelGrid}" >
</h:panelGrid>
```

the form is rendered!!

So i guess the object dynamicPanelGrid is populated...

Any ideas on how to change my code in order for the form to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

`dynamicPanelGrid` is name of your field (property). Getter and setter should look like this:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // init your dynamicPanelGrid
}

public HtmlPanelGrid getDynamicPanelGrid() {
    return dynamicPanelGrid;
}

public void setDynamicPanelGrid(HtmlPanelGrid dynamicPanelGrid) {
    this.dynamicPanelGrid = dynamicPanelGrid;
}
```

Read about [Java Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/index.html).

Than your binding attribute should look like this:

```
binding="#{reviewReportBean.dynamicPanelGrid}"
```

Comment: Obviously i am a newby at java beans but you mean that it should work if i put the code of "public HtmlPanelGrid dynamicPanelGrid()" into my getter?